# how do you remove {} from xtable output

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have this markdown,

````
---
title: "TEST"
date: "`r date()`"

header-includes:
   - \usepackage{longtable}
   - \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
   - \usepackage{colortbl}
   - \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   - \usepackage{graphicx}
   - \usepackage{wrapfig}
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    fig_height: 6
    fig_width: 7
    highlight: zenburn
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 4
keep_tex: yes
tables: yes
fontsize: 15
---

```{r message=FALSE, results = 'asis', echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.width=12, fig.height=10}
library(xtable)

glossary2<-data.frame(names=letters[1:4],definition=c("very long long long text very long long long text very long long long text very long long long text","very long long long long long text","very long long long long long long text","very long long long text"),include=c(NA,"YES",NA,"NO"))
glossaryprin<-xtable(glossary2,label="tab:codebook",caption="glossary")

align(glossaryprin)<-"lp{2in}p{3in}p{1in}" #here is the change
print(glossaryprin,tabular.environment="longtable",floating=FALSE,size="\\fontsize{30pt}{10pt}\\selectfont")
```
````

I can I get rid of { and } outside of the xtable output table?

Comment: which brackets are you referring to? The only brackets I see are required for proper latex...

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- gsub('[{}]', '', df)
```

Is this what you're looking for?